# How do I grant the necessary permissions to insert into pg_enum?

Tags: postgresql, enums

How do I grant the necessary permissions to insert into pg_enum?

I get this error: ERROR:  permission denied for relation pg_enum
SQL state: 42501

And none of my grant statements grant the required privileges.

Comment: Unless you messed with the database, everybody has permissions to select from `pg_catalog.pg_enum`. What do you get for `SELECT relacl FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'pg_enum';`?

Comment: You don't insert into system catalogs. If you want to create an enum, use `create type`

Comment: The enum exists.  We want to use the standard postgres way of inserting a new value into the enum.

Comment: Use [`alter type`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertype.html) then. Never try to change system catalogs manually

Comment: There are valid reasons to insert into system catalog directly, namely if you are trying to alter an enum from within a transaction (where the enum is used in a column so you can't rename).  In general, while it's useful to specify alternatives to what the question asks, the real answer is not to say that a question is invalid.